# Flutter type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<PostModel>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart

I'm trying to create a list using bloc and rxdart but I get an error type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream?' I am using rxdart: ^0.27.1. Just want to put the **Array response** in list.

**My List screen**

```
 Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.fetchPosts(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PostModel> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildList(snapshot);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

**PostBloc bloc**
Maybe the error is here when using stream but i'm unable to find the error.

```
 class PostBloc {
    final _repository = PostRepository();
    final _postsFetcher = PublishSubject<PostModel>();

    Stream<PostModel> get allPosts => _postsFetcher.stream;

    fetchPosts() async {
    PostModel itemModel = await _repository.fetchAllPosts();
    _postsFetcher.sink.add(itemModel);
     }

     dispose() {
    _postsFetcher.close();
     }
    }

final bloc = PostBloc();
```

**Post Repository**

```
    class PostRepository {
    final postApiProvider = PostApiProvider();
    Future<PostModel> fetchAllPosts() => postApiProvider.getPostList();
    }
```

**Post ApiProvider**

```
class PostApiProvider {
  Client client = Client();

  Future<PostModel> getPostList() async {
    print("entered");
    final response = await client
        .get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
    print(response.body.toString());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      return PostModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post {
  late int userId;
  late int id;
  late String title;
  late String body;

  Post(result) {
    userId = result['userId'];
    id = result['id'];
    title = result['title'];
    body = result['body'];
  }

  int get getUserID => userId;

  int get getID => id;

  String get getTitle => title;

  String get getBody => body;

}

class PostModel {
  List<Post> results = [];

  PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Post> temp = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++) {
      Post result = Post(parsedJson[i]);
      temp.add(result);
    }
    results = temp;
  }

  List<Post> get getResults => results;
}
```

**Sample Response**

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept of `BLoC` is first you have to put data in stream with the help of `sink` and then you can get data from stream with help of `Stream`.

In your code, You're using sink function as a `StreamBuilder's` stream. Which is incorrect. You should call stream like below,

```
  StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.allPosts, /// THIS IS STREAM OF DATA
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PostModel> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return buildList(snapshot);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
```

Call your sink function in initState or wherever you want like this

```
bloc.fetchPosts(); /// THIS WILL TRIGGER YOUR API
```

Second issue is in model, It's about datatype. The response you're getting from API is `List<dynamic>` and you have declared `Map<String, dynamic>`. Which is incorrect. Define as below

```
class PostModel {
  List<Post> results = [];

  PostModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Post> temp = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++) {
      Post result = Post(parsedJson[i]);
      temp.add(result);
    }
    results = temp;
  }

  List<Post> get getResults => results;
}
```

And one last thing, You forgot to return your model in `fetchPosts()` function

```
Future<PostModel> fetchPosts() async {
    PostModel itemModel = await _repository.fetchAllPosts();
    _postsFetcher.sink.add(itemModel);
    return itemModel;
  }
```

Comment: Quick question. what if the reply is an object not an array what do I change?

Comment: Then give a data type according to your Object in model class.

Comment: same above but without the [], basically the details of the list

Comment: Then go with `Map<String,dynamic>` or `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` data type